# Creating a simple table in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to create a simple table with big font (as an image) of csv data in Python using matploylib such as the one seen here:

[Newbie Matplotlib and Pandas Plotting from CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806575/newbie-matplotlib-and-pandas-plotting-from-csv-file)

Comment: Try the accepted answer to convert your dataframe (df) into a png from matplotlib - https://stackoverflow.com/q/35634238/18192997

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of these:

1. [jupyter notebook](https://jupyter.org/) and its styles
2. [pretty_html_table](https://github.com/sbi-rviot/ph_table)(Beautiful html tables made easy )